# Where in the UK may I find a register or map of properties and their energy use

Tags: united-kingdom, data

I am  looking for a register of the energy use of buildings in the uk with granularity down to individual builing. Is this publically available? I recall that this information is collected when processing energy certificates

Comment: This question might be better on http://opendata.stackexchange.com/, which also has a gis tag, but it will be interesting to see what the answer is.

Comment: I don't know but I too would be very interested to find out. I've heard there may be an open source library of energy consumption from smart meter data in the pipeline, but that might well be a pipe dream...who knows. I suggest following @JohnBarca's advice.

Answer (score 1):

There is something here which may be useful.

http://data.gov.uk/dataset/non-domestic-energy-performance-certificate-register/feedback/view

Comment: It's better to provide some elaboration or summary in your answer rather than just a link. For example, which of the 45 search results your link leads to are you specifically suggesting may be useful? What data does it contain, or in what format? Right now this reads more like a comment than an answer and may be flagged as low quality.

Comment: Sorry Chris I was on a bad connection and lost the link. Here it is.  http://data.gov.uk/dataset/non-domestic-energy-performance-certificate-register/feedback/view , its an unpublished register of non domestic energy performance certificates.

Comment: You can use the **edit** button at the lower left of your question or answer to make revisions or provide clarifying details. And I'm afraid even with the updated link, it takes you to a result that isn't data though it indicates that data may be available for a fee (which conflicts with your open-data tag). These are the kinds of details that are good to include in such an answer. This still reads more like a comment on your question than an answer.